# Injecting IServiceCollection in my custom middleware

Tags: dependency-injection, middleware, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to make a custom middleware that registers that `ApplicationDbContext`outside the `ConfigureServices` method. Basically, I want to move this:

```
_services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(......);
```

outside of the `ConfigureServices` method and to the application pipeline via a custom middleware.

This is what my custom middleware looks like:

```
 public class MyMW
{
    IConfiguration _configuration;
    RequestDelegate _next;
    IServiceCollection _services;
    public MyMW(RequestDelegate next, IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _next = next;
        _services = services;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        //Add DbContext
        _services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(....);


        //Add Identity
        _services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        ......    
        await _next.Invoke(context);
        ......
    }
}
```

I have injected `IServiceCollection` in the custom middleware to use it to register the database provider in my middleware. There is also an extension method to use the middleware in the `Configure` method.

```
public static class MyMWExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMW(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyMW>();
    }
}
```

I'm getting

`InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' while attempting to activate 'TestProgram.MyMW'.`

Which I think is trying to tell me that I can't inject `IServiceCollection` in to my custom middleware. My end goal is make custom middlewares that will allow me to use different database providers. For eg, a middle that allows SQLServer will be called `SqlServerMiddleware`, `SqliteMiddleware` and so on.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. The line in `ConfigureServices` just registers the services in the container. Once you get into the middleware pipeline, you're already dealing with a particular request, and it's too late to register services. However, the actual instances are only created when utilized for the first time in the scope they're registered in. In other words, if you're trying to delay creation of the context until later, that's already the case.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Sorry for not being clear, I am trying to move the database registration part out from `ConfigureServices` method and move it into a custom middleware that I will include in my pipeline. Is it possible to do this? Can I register the database service after the container is closed and we've moved on to the `Configure` method?

Comment: No. Once the service provider has been built, you can't add additional services to it. You don't necessarily need to put the code in `ConfigureServices`, but it must be done before the app is run. The middleware pipeline is too late.

Comment: Right, Thanks. So could we implementing something like this if we register the database context in the container but we select the provider via options later on in our custom middleware? Would that work? Adding a simple `services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();` in the `ConfigureServices` and then using `options => options.UseSqlServer(......)` in the middleware Constructor/Invoke method.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Can you please add your second response as an answer so I can mark it? Thanks

Comment: The configuration of dependency injection must be performed in a single place: composition root. If you pass IServiceCollection somewhere else, then you violate the principles of DI, bind to a specific implementation of the IoC-container and use the Service Locator anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [Factory-based middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to achieve this